# Can Crafting be Profitable?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I’ve got a lot of junk I need to clear out of my inventory. Selling to merchants is all well and good, but can I do any value-add before I unload my packs to increase my rate of return? Are any of the things I can make worth more than simply selling all of the component parts to a vendor?

Comment: In my opinion, no. I feel that crafted items.yield less shards than raw resources used to create them.

Comment: Feeling don't enter into it. It's a question of math that I am too lazy to do, and assume someone else has done!

Comment: I'll be happy to test this next time I play it. But as far as I remember, I've always sold resources because they worth more than potions and traps.

Answer (score 2):

This is limited to potions and traps. Any kind of ammunition cannot be sold.

As for the value of components vs items, as an example:

A health potion can be sold for 6 shards. However, to make a health potion you need 2 "Rich meat" and 3 "Fatty meat". Rich meat sells for 3 shards per item, and Fatty meat sells for 2 shards per item, meaning that by selling the items, you get double the value of the potion.

The upside is that a lot of the time, Potions and traps are found in loot boxes or treasure boxes, on human enemies, etc. So in those situations, you can fill up your stock of potions and traps fairly quickly, without expending your meat stocks.

As for stocking up on ammo parts - firstly, you can never have too much Ridgewood. If you *need* to keep things limited, I keep it down to 3 stacks at the very least. For all other items required for ammunition, I keep at least one stack, two stacks if I'm feeling generous (items like blaze, chillwater, sparkers, etc).

Comment: Yeah I’m pretty good on understanding my keep vs. sell quotas and not really asking about that here. Was just trying to figure out if there was any value on turning all my meat into potions or blaze into traps (etc). before turning it into shards at a merchant. 

Doesn’t sound like the math makes this worthwhile though, so it’s time to sell a bunch of meat.